# Drupal Get Nodes by Author ID

Tags: drupal

Is there a function in the Drupal API that I can use to get nodes by author ID?

I am trying to create a block that shows the current user a list of their authored pages and I'm having a surprisingly difficult time with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easily done with SQL:

```
global $user;
$items = array();
$result = db_query("SELECT nid, title FROM {node} WHERE uid = %d", $user->uid);
while ($row = db_fetch_object($result)) {
  $items[] = l($row->title, 'node/' . $row->nid);
}
return theme('item_list', $items, NULL, 'ul');
```

The above code in a custom block should do the trick. Just remember not to cache it.

Comment: I had been looking for an API function as I am working in such a situation where I can't directly access the database this drupal installation is running on. So I couldn't see records or column names or anything. Thanks so much for such a complete answer!

Comment: You can use the backup and migrate module to take a copy of the db into your local enviroment, if you need to give it a look.

Comment: An SQL query in a block doesn't seem very "Drupally"

Comment: @Naoise you write the code In a custom module. This is how to do it. It is what views does when it creates a block.

Comment: How do i do this in **Drupal 8** ?

Answer (score 10):

You could be using the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module for this. It generates pages, blocks, feeds, and more via a web UI that lets you construct a database query. Very slick, and heavily used on most Drupal sites.

Comment: Agreed, this seems like a perfect use case for Views.